How to find where an application freezes?
I have a large C++ application that reproducibly freezes at a certain point. It does not crash, no segfault. I have access to the source code, but I'm not the author. Thus I can't make an educated guess about what is going on.
I tried to use gdb to debug it. The problem is however, that when I hit a breakpoint, the application freezes. When I'm stepping through, the application also appears frozen. Thus I can't really distinguish, whether or not I have found a problem, or if the application simply appears frozen because execution is paused in the debugger.
I fear that my best bet would be to go back to good old cout debugging. Are there any other options?

Run the program, without breakpoints or stepping. When it "freeze" then break the program to find out where in the code it happens. Is it an infinite loop? Is it a function that waits for something (like input)?

It can also be a deadlock, so also be sure to investigate all the threads and which locks/mutexes they are holding/trying to enter. And that too requires an attached debugger

go back to good old cout debugging How about adding a log class if there isn't one already. With that said I agree with the above comments.

As for the development process, how many unit tests does the code base have?

maybe thread sanitizer or valgrind will be a friend? You may get directly a dread lock report from the tools.

"good old cout debugging" involves writing code to debug the broken code you wrote.  What could possibly be wrong with that?!

@Clifford by adding cout logging you can change the timing/behavior of the code which can (and will) have an impact on race conditions... it is really not a good way of debugging for those kind of issues.

@PepijnKramer - so we are agreeing with each other.  I think you may have missed my sarcasm.  I am saying that if you have written broken code, writing more code to fix it is a flawed approach.  The timing issue is another reason - I work in real-time embedded systems; I am well aware. You need to address your comment at the OP.

You can simple attach to a program when it is frozen, and then inspect the current state (e.g. with bt).

Possible it is "frozen" because you have called a function that is waiting for input.  If you step-over such a function, the debugger will not halt until the function returns (by providing the requisite input perhaps).
Alternatively you have stepped over a non-returning function because the function itself is incorrect or was provided incorrect parameters.
Either way, the appropriate strategy is to run the program until it appears to be "frozen", then halt the program to determine where it is stuck. Likely this is in some library code with no source code available.  In that case you should inspect the call stack to determine how it got to where it is, and in particular traceback to the call that was recognisably your code.
In gdb ctrl+c will halt the running process.  The where command will output the call stack.
